# Is Apache's RewriteCond HTTP_Referer secure against referer spoofing?

Tags: apache, security, http, mod-rewrite, http-referer

Is `RewriteCond HTTP_Referer` in Apache safe to block direct access to scripts or data included in a private (password-protected, not through Apache's `mod_auth`) HTML page?

Or could someone use Referer Spoofing to gain access to the scripts and data?

Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?.(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(txt|js|pdf)$
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking but it is definitely possible to spoof the header

Comment: If you already know that the referrer is “spoof-able”, then how can this even be still an unanswered question to you …?

Comment: CBroe - I wanted to know whether referer spoofing was possible with Apache or whether Apache offered in-built security against it. (Beginner to Apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite conditions check for an HTTP client header (`Referer`).
As such the user/attacker is totally free to send you whatever value she wants, aka. she can spoof the header.

Hence, it is not secure regarding authenticated sessions (you mentioned password-protected areas)!

It is only helpful against other sites hotlinking your resources and therefore "stealing" your traffic. But even in this scenario, you should consider the downsides, such as your site breaking for people who spoof/remove referrers e.g. due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Are there any methods to block access to images/files/data included in a HTML page from unauthenticated users (without mod_auth)? I know you can put PHP includes outside of public_html; is there any way to do this with HTML?

Comment: With "just" HTML? No. How you'd do it would depend on your authentication scheme, middleware, etc. In the end *something* server site much check the auth status of the request before returning data.

Comment: Is there any way to secure files included in HTML code (e.g. <img src=> or <script>) from being accessed outside of the password-protected page index.php?